# Specialization Soundness - Lemma for Soundness Theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

To prove the *Soundness Theorem*, I first have to prove the following **Lemma**: ***Every specialization of a sound inference rule is itself sound as well.***

**My try**: I've tried to prove the equivalent claim to this theorem: given a model (maps each literal to *True*/*False*) that shows the specialization of a general inference rule is unsound, prove so is the general one. But, I couldn't find a proper way to prove it.

Just to ensure we have the same definitions to the above:

- *Specialization of an inference rule* - An inference rule $\beta$ is a specialization of an inference rule $\alpha$ if there exist several formulas $\phi_1$, ..., $\phi_n$ and a matching number of variable names
  $v_1$, ..., $v_n$, such that β is obtained from α by (simultaneously) substituting the formula $\phi_i$ for each occurrence of the variable name $v_i$ in all of the assumptions of α (while maintaining the order of the assumptions) as well as in its conclusion. For example, we may have the *general* rule  $(q \implies r)$ which can be specialized to $((p \lor p) \implies r)$.
- *Soundness* - We say that a set $A$ of formulas **entails** a formula $\phi$ if every model that satisfies all the assumptions in $A$ also satisfies $\varphi$.

Can you help me prove the theorem using the direction in my try?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. For the mathematics, Given a model $M$ that satisfies the assumptions of an inference rule where each $v_i$ has been specialised to $\phi_i$, what can you say about the original rule in a model where each $v_i$ has been interpreted as the value  of $\phi_i$ in $M$?

Comment: @RobArthan So in this case, the original rule would be satisfied as well, but it doesn't give us a respective satisfying model for each of the original inference rule's literals.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You don't need to do any proof by contradiction from this: just work forward from what you now about the original rule to get what you want to know about the specialised rule.

Comment: @RobArthan Suppose I want to continue with my try (going in the opposite direction), how can one prove it? Let $(p \land q) \implies r$ and $((z \lor x) \land m) \implies q$ be general and specialized inference rules respectively, with an unsatisfying model for the specialized one: $z: True, x: False, m: True, q: False$, how can one use this model to find an unsatisfying model for the general one?

Comment: $p \land q \implies r$ isn't sound. It has instances that are sound, e.g., $a \land a \implies a$. Try specialising a sound rule like $p \land q \implies p$ and see what happens.

Comment: From your description of your proof sketch for soundness theorem, it's better for you to first understand a term called [logical harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_harmony) coined by contemporary philosopher Michael Dummett. Soundness theorem like completeness theorem, a true proof has to consider each inference rule in your meta-system and then use induction on the height of derivation...